# EXCEL VBA FIND Value and then sum and then delete other row

Tags: excel, vba, search

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w16DP.png)[enter image description here][2]Hi,

I have an issue and hopefully someone can help. I have an Excel sheet and I Need to check if starting from last row if the same value as in column 4 from last row exists somewhere above, but condition is, that only if column 1 and column 2 are same and not in column 3 is the word "SK" or "SV" and then I Need to sum the values in column 7 and concaternate column 3 and column 6 and just Keep one line and the other which were the base of this calculation must be deleted.

Attached you will find the screenshots. First how the Excel file Looks like before processing and next screenshot how it should look like afterwards.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w16DP.png)

Comment: Your sample didn't not include anything in column 4 on the last line, so I added 9105000 to get the results in your 2nd screenshot.  Try this code and see if it does what you want......

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
Sub combine_data()

    Dim vLastRow As Integer
    Dim Col_A_Str As String
    Dim Col_B_Str As String
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim vDatarow As Integer
    Dim vCodeStr3 As String
    Dim vCodeStr6 As String
    Dim vTotal As Double
    Dim Col_D_Str As String

    vLastRow = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
    Col_A_Str = ""
    Col_B_Str = ""
    r = 1
    vDatarow = 0
    vCodeStr3 = ""
    vCodeStr6 = ""
    vTotal = 0
    Col_D_Str = ""

    Col_A_Str = Trim(Cells(vLastRow, 1))
    Col_B_Str = Trim(Cells(vLastRow, 2))
    Col_D_Str = Trim(Cells(vLastRow, 4))

    Do Until r = vLastRow

        DoEvents

        If Trim(Cells(r, 4)) = Col_D_Str Then

            If Trim(Cells(r, 1)) = Col_A_Str Then

                If Trim(Cells(r, 2)) = Col_B_Str Then

                    If UCase(Trim(Cells(r, 3))) <> "SV" And UCase(Trim(Cells(r, 3))) <> "SK" Then

                        If vDatarow = 0 Then

                            If vDatarow = 0 Then vDatarow = r

                            vCodeStr3 = Trim(Cells(r, 3))
                            vCodeStr6 = Trim(Cells(r, 6))
                            vTotal = Cells(r, 7)

                            r = r + 1

                        Else

                            vCodeStr3 = vCodeStr3 & ", " & Trim(Cells(r, 3))
                            vCodeStr6 = vCodeStr6 & ", " & Trim(Cells(r, 6))
                            vTotal = vTotal + Cells(r, 7)

                            Cells(r, 1).EntireRow.Delete
                            vLastRow = vLastRow - 1

                        End If

                    Else

                        r = r + 1

                    End If

                Else

                     r = r + 1

                End If

            Else

                 r = r + 1

            End If

         Else

            r = r + 1

        End If

    Loop

    Cells(vDatarow, 3).ClearContents
    Cells(vDatarow, 3) = vCodeStr3

    Cells(vDatarow, 6).ClearContents
    Cells(vDatarow, 6) = vCodeStr6

    Cells(vDatarow, 7).ClearContents
    Cells(vDatarow, 7) = vTotal

End Sub
```